# Data types and documentation for for-loop in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, utf-8

I am very confused about the data types and UTF-8 encoding. What is actually happening under the hood? I am reading a messy JSON data without delimiters in Python 3 (data has Japanese/Chinese characters time to time).

I am reading in the data:

```
url = "http://localhost:8001"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
type(data)
```

And it returns *bytes* at the moment

Then I want to read it letter by letter

```
for letter in data:
    type(letter)
```

It returns me that letter is an *integer* right now. Why it was a byte and now it is an integer?
P.S. I understand that the integer that I am getting represents a decimal representation of the character. But this jumping back and forth makes me confused.

P.S. I also couldn't find official documentation for for-loop. Is there one?

Thank you.

Comment: _"Why it was a byte and now it is an integer?_" What is "it" here? `letter`? But `letter` was never a byte. `data`? But `data` is never an integer. This seems equivalent to the question "Why does `x = [1,2,3]; print(type(x)); print(type(x[0]))` print 'list' and then 'int'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decoding the data as Padraic Cunningham suggested should work:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
```

You also asked for the official documentatio for the for-loop. I'm not sure if you refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) or you are talking about the iteration behaviour of `data`.

The iteration behaviour of a `bytes` is as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object b, b[0] will be an integer, while b[0:1] will be a bytes object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)

Not enough rep to post it as a comment to the previous answer, I'm sorry.

Comment: Adirio, thanks for the documentation. Yes, I was looking for that. Can you also share about the iteration behavior of data please? I am not quite sure what you mean :) I'll read it later.

Comment: Edited my asnwer to include the info you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the [*bytes*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) to *str*:

```
In [12]: data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014233/data-types-and-documentation-for-for-loop-in-python-3/38014292#38014292").read()

In [13]: type(data)
Out[13]: bytes

In [14]: type(data.decode("utf-8"))
Out[14]: str

In [15]: data[0]
Out[15]: 60

In [16]: data.decode("utf-8")[0]
Out[16]: '<'
```

After decoding you will get see the characters when you loop and print. *`urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()`* returns *bytes*, it is up to you to decode the bytes into a str.

Comment: Thank you, that actually helps a lot. My main concern, why for-loop returns integer instead of the byte?

Comment: @Cooper, that is shown in my answer, `data[0] -> 60` as it has not be decoded to a str, after decoding `data.decode("utf-8")[0]  -> "<"`. The for loop iterates over each byte so all you see are the int/byte values, what do you not understand? Have you decoded and run your for loop?

Comment: @Cooper: Because `bytes` object iterate over the numeric value of each individual byte. Nothing to do with a `for` loop specifically, it's just how `bytes` implements the iterator protocol. If you did `list(data)`, you'd get a `list` of `int`.